# Routes com AngularJS e Node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, route

Aprendi um pouco sobre AngularJS e agora estou começando com Node.js e surgiram algumas dúvidas. Com o Angular eu uso `$routeProvider` pra criar as rotas e navegar entre as páginas como single page application, no Node também consegui usar as rotas, mas surgiu a dúvida de como usar as duas ou se, usando angular e node, eu devo usar as rotas em um ou outro.

Li várias coisas e pelo o que eu vi, devo usar as rotas pelo node apenas, é isso mesmo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guerra, o $routeProvider é usado apenas no front-end e serve para navegar entre as páginas. Com ele você pode definir a controladora e layout de cada página.

O nodejs é um servidor (backend). As rotas que você cria no Express são serviços REST e
você pode fazer requisições para esses serviços por meio do $http do angular.

Answer (score 1):

O certo é usar somente o node,

Com o express você provavelmente vai querer capturar todas as requisições e mandar para o seu index.html exemplo:

```
app = express();
app.use(app.router);
app.use(function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

[fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222252/how-to-use-angularjs-routes-with-express-node-js-when-a-new-page-is-requested)

Comment: Entendi. Então o ngRoute seria apenas para páginas web ou aplicações que não usam node e express? Obrigado.